# Objective C difference between * and ^

Tags: objective-c

I am learning objective C.

Just wondering the difference between `*` and `^`.

I know `*` is means point to memory right?

```
NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

But today I encountered the `^` symbol. Anyone can help explain, please?

```
-(void) sort
{
    [book sortUsingComparator:
    ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [obj1 compareNames: obj2];
    } ];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` is for a plain old c pointer.  `^` is for a block (proc, closure, lambda).  Specifically,  a block in Objective-C is implemented as a Closure.

`^` is essentially a function pointer with some scope-related side-effects that discriminately copy the necessary objects and primitives so that when the block (function) is called, the variables in the block are a copy of the ones that were in the external scope where the block was defined.

Blocks are a very large and somewhat complex topic in Objective-C. You can find a very concise overview [here](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/programming-with-blocks-an-overview/).

The BIG comprehensive stuff can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) in Apple's documentation.

EDIT:

In your specific example...

```
-(void) sort
{
    [book sortUsingComparator:
    ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [obj1 compareNames: obj2];
    } ];
}
```

The method `sortUsingComparator:` takes an anonymous block as a parameter.  The simplified block signature is `^(id obj1, id obj)`.  Simplified meaning that since the return type is `void`, it can be left out.  What makes this example confusing to many people is that the block is actually defined in-line, right in the middle of a method call.

This code would be easier to read if the block were first declared with a descriptive name and then defined like any other c function, and then the *name* used in the method call.  But, it seems that most developers don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

`^` is related to blocks in Objective-C. Take a look at [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1).

Answer (score 2):

`*` is used for pointer as well as for multiplication.

```
NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

Here `test` is a pointer to `NSString`.

---

```
^(id obj1, id
```

`^` is used to [create](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Block.html) a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1).

---

**If you are familiar with C/C++ then :**

Here is a C Function Pointer Declaration...

```
 void (*func)(void);
```

and here is a Block Declaration...

```
 void (^block)(void);
```